# Converting .dat files to shapefiles

Tags: shapefile, convert

We have electrical conductivity maps of our fields created using a [Veris sensor](https://www.veristech.com/) that are in a .dat file type. We want to import these maps into our [Ag leader SMS database](https://support.agleader.com/kbp/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=1549), but in order to do that, they need to be converted to shapefiles.

How would I go about converting them?

Comment: What information is in the .dat file? you need an ETL tool to convert the data if it is usable format.

Comment: Other file formats are supported by Ag leader ~ https://support.agleader.com/kbp/index.php?View=afile&EntryID=1549&AttachID=5205

Comment: Is this some kind of GPS file?  If so, GPS Babel might be able to convert it to a KML.  Then use QGIS to create the shapefile. https://www.gpsbabel.org/capabilities.html

Comment: 20/20 Seed Sense (*.dat) but most likely a different encoded format

Comment: Possibly this will help : http://farmworks.co.uk/forum/read.php?9,72080,72658,  you should be able to open in Excel, save as CSV and import into SMS database

Comment: Are you able to use Python? If so I have a script that converts .dat files to shapefiles. What are the columns with spatial data in your .dat file?

Comment: There's columns for lat, lon, and elevation, as well as two other columns for shalow and deep electrical conductivity.

Comment: Can you let us have a sample file? Otherwise we're guessing.

Answer (score 2):

As you have confirmed that the file format is (per my comment) as described in the link [Re: .dat file from Veris Machine How to Read](http://farmworks.co.uk/forum/read.php?9,72080,72658)

> There are five columns of data logged by a Veris machine:
>   Column A: Longitude
>   Column B: Latitude
>   Column C: Shallow EC
>   Column D: Deep EC
>   Column E: Elevation

You should as per that post be able to import the .dat file into Excel add the appropriate column headings and export as CSV.

You say you need a shapefile to import into the Ag leader SMS database, but the [Ag Leader support documentation](https://support.agleader.com/kbp/index.php?View=afile&EntryID=1549&AttachID=5205) tells us that CSV file format is supported, so you should be able to import the CSV directly.